# I built an html page use of j query when i zoom this page some image is not responsive and right side image is only scroll-able

Tags: jquery, css, html

```
<body background="bg_slide02.jpg" style="background-repeat:no-repeat;background-attachment:fixed;">

<p class="rcorners" style="font-size: 20px;position: fixed;" align="top"><b  >Demo</b></p>

<img src="Blutgefaesse_ausschnitt.png" id="afterimg" style="
    height: 50%;
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 9%;
    margin-left: 10%;
" >
<div style="margin-top:45%;position: fixed;background-image:url(box_02.png);margin-left: 10%;background-repeat: no-repeat;" id="box" >
     <img src="box_01.png" style="margin-top: 5%;">
</div>

<img src="Blutgefaesse.png" style="height: 200%;margin-top: 20%;float: right;zoom: 100%;">
```

**Problem:** When I zoom(in browser) this page some image is not responsive and i make only right side image is scroll-able.I fix all image position.I want to all image responsive and work as working demo

**Working demo(updated):** http://jsfiddle.net/mohsin80/q80tLvsd/2/

Comment: The images are in your Dropbox account, so in the example only visible by you. You have to upload the images to a public server images to see the example correctly.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mohsin80/q80tLvsd/2/     updated

Comment: The images are still in a private account, this time is a https://lh3.googleusercontent.com. You must to upload to a full public acces server like www.imageupload.co.uk or http://postimage.org

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mohsin80/q80tLvsd/3/ final updated provide solution...  juan c.v

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i think i can see the problem. You've put the position attribute fixed for some elements, and this makes the position remains unchanged on the screen even when you scroll.

Try changing the position attribute from fixed to absolute, and you can do scroll with all elements of the page:

```
<body background="http://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2015/09/24/bg_slide02.jpg" style="background-repeat:no-repeat; background-attachment:fixed;">

    <p class="rcorners" style="font-size: 20px;position: absolute;" align="top"><b>Demo</b></p>

    <img src="http://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2015/09/24/Blutgefaesse_ausschnitt.png" id="afterimg" style="height:50%; position:absolute; margin-top:9%; margin-left:10%;" >
    <div style="margin-top:45%; position:absolute; background-image:url(http://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2015/09/24/box_02.png); margin-left:10%; background-repeat:no-repeat;" id="box">
        <img src="http://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2015/09/24/box_01.png" style="margin-top:5%;">
    </div>

    <img src="http://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2015/09/24/Blutgefaesse.png" style="height:200%; margin-top:20%; float:right;">
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q80tLvsd/11/

I also see that you try to interact with some element using jQuery, the problem is that there is no element with the id "img1"

One question, what do you mean *"I want to all image responsive and work as working demo"*? What do you mean by that images are responsive?

Comment: thx for the ans but that is not my solution.i want to only scroll Blutgefaesse.png and remaining is fix position and when i zoom the page all image is remaining in page.